# Why can the job offer have a negative relationship between salary and quantity of work?

Tags: labor-economics

Excuse me the following question arose, is it possible that the job offer has a negative relationship between salary and the amount of work?

Comment: Are you referring to amount of work demanded by the employer against certain salary or the amount of work you are willing to do against a certain salary?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is! Look up *Borjas, Labor Economics*, in the Labor Supply chapter.

In the following graph you notice that the supply curve is upwards sloping until wage $W = 20$, but for any greater level of compensation, the worker does not need to work as hard anymore, and starts reducing their hours of labor.

[image]

For an example, you might want to imagine a young music performer. If their earnings from concerts are, say, $ W = \\\$800 $ a month, they might have to gig a lot. As their music becomes known, their earnings from concerts might exceed $ W=\\\$8000 $, at which point, they may decide to work less, thus, reducing their number of concerts.